# Vba: Add comments to a Named Range passed through a variable

Tags: excel, vba

Could not find an answer to the '1004' Run time error I receive when I try to assign a comment to a named range.
I am trying to create from a list in a spreadsheet named ranges. In the spreadsheet I provide "Name", "Range", "Comment" in 3 columns, where "Name" and "Comment" are strings and "Range" is a formula, usually containing OFFSET.

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyOU1.png)

```
Sub FromListCreateNamedRanges()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Settings")
    For i = 2 To LastRow2(wks, 5)
        CreateNamedRanges wks.Cells(i, 5), wks.Cells(i, 6).Formula, wks.Cells(i, 7)
    Next
End Sub

Sub CreateNamedRanges(str_rngname As String, var_formula As Variant, Optional str_comment As String)
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=str_rngname, RefersTo:=var_formula
    ThisWorkbook.Names(str_rngname).Comment = str_comment
End Sub
```

LastRow2 is a user function to determine the last row of a given column. Everything works without using

```
ThisWorkbook.Names(str_rngname).Comment = str_comment
```

With the above line I receive an error message. I would appreciate your help, suggestions and ideas.

Comment: Your sub `CreateNamedRanges` worked for me for some simple test cases --- comments worked too. Maybe `str_comment` has something Excel doesn't like. Maybe Excel munges names is special cases so that `ThisWorkbook.Names(str_rngname)` fails. You could try `Dim nm as Name` followed by `Set nm = ThisWorkbook.Names.Add(...)` and `nm.Comment = ...`.

Comment: xidgel, thank you for your response. Unfortunately, I still receive the error. Could it have anything to do with me using a non-English Excel version. When I used the macro recorder and change the string "Test" in `.Comment = "Test"` it works. However, trying to pass it through a variable fails. The error message says something like "there is an error in the formula. This is not a formula?..." .

Comment: can you post the content of  "var_formula" variable?

Comment: RADO, var_formula = `"=OFFSET(Master!$A$1,1,,s_CountData-1,1)"`

Answer (score 0):

This strange behavior upon modifying a comment on a named range is triggered by the formula in `.RefersTo`

When the formula is somehow too complex the runtime error is thrown when you attempt to modify the comment but NOT when you attempt to modify the reference

An easy workaround is:

1. to put a temporary simple reference in the `.RefersTo` property
2. to modify the `.comment` property as you want
3. to put the permanent complex reference in the `.RefersTo` property